# Access the DTO elements

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot

I am stuck with an issue and not sure how to proceed with it.

I have a DTO something like this :-

ORDER DTO:-

```
[
    {
        "ordNo": "77456",

        "patients" :[   :- THIS DTO IS SHOTPATIENTDTO
        {
            "patientFirstName" : "Test",
            "patientLastName" : "Dummy",
            "patientDob" : "2018-01-04",
            "patientUr" : "12345",
            "patientId" : "1",    
            "batches" :[    //:------SHOTTEMPBACTH DTO
            {
                "batchId":"37",  :- for each of the ID, I will set the BATCHDTO
                "treatmentDateTime": "2017-12-06 17:55:50",
                "status":"Submitted"
            },
            {
                "batchId":"38",
                "treatmentDateTime": "2017-12-06 17:55:50",
                "Status":"On Hold"
            }]
        },
        {
          "patientFirstName" : "Second",
            "patientLastName" : "Dummy",
            "patientDob" : "2018-01-04",
            "patientUr" : "542",
            "patientId" : "1",    
            "batches" :[
            {
                "batchId":"39",
                "treatmentDateTime": "2017-12-06 17:55:50",
                "status":"Submitted"
            },
            {
                "batchId":"40",
                "treatmentDateTime": "2017-12-06 17:55:50",
                "Status":"On Hold"
            }]
        }]    
}]
```

I have an enitity which is ORDER having one to many relationship with BATCH TABLE.

Order which has a list of Batches(retrieve the batch using the batchId and set the object using the ORDER DTO) and there is another entity as SHOT_BATCH which conists of Batch + some additional attributes like patient details.

So while constructing my shotbatch entity for saving,

I am doing like this 
[1]

```
 for ( each of the order, get me the batches)
 {
     create an object of SHOTBATCH and set the properties
 }

 DAO.save(SHOTBATCH)
```

My question, I would like to set the patient name for each of the batches. How shall I iterate in order to get that ? In the above example, I would be 
getting 4 batches(37-40) in the above loop[1]. so how can I determine which patient belongs to which batch so that I can set it in the SHOTBATCH.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if I got something wrong about your question. I understand that you want to build a collection and batch save it rather that calling DAO.save for every batchShot object. I would approach it in this way:

Lets say that we have the BatchShot object:

```
class ShotBatch {
  private List<Shot> shots;

  private String patientName;

  public ShotBatch(final String patientName, final Shot[] shots) {
    this.shots = Arrays.asList(shots);
    this.patientName = patientName;
  }

  // getters setters
}
```

Then the create and save code would be:

```
List<ShotBatch> patientBatches = new ArrayList<>();
for (final Order order: orders) {
  for (final Patient patient: order.getPatients()) {
    // Assuming that patien has method getFullName that returns a String
    // and getShots that returns an array of Shots
    patientBatches.add(new ShotBatch(patient.getFullName(), patient.getShots()));
  }
}

ShotBatchDao.saveAll(patientBatches);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.Unfortunately, that's not the case. I have the DTO as an input but I want to find out which patient is mapped to a batch object.In my ShotBatchDTO,I have this {

   private string patientname;
   private String patient last name;
   
   and so with their getters/setters
   
}

Comment: Now in my repository class, I am receiving the above ORDER DTO as an input. So I have to fetch the details of the batches and patient for each of the batches.



 for ( each of the order, get me the batches)
  {
      create an object of SHOTBATCH and set the properties
   shotbatch.setpatientname(how to get from the DTO);
   //similarly for other patient attributes.
     }
  
  List<SHOTBATCH> DAO.save(SHOTBATCH)

Comment: ORDERDTO[]
    ...
 SHOTPATIENTDTO[]
    SHOTBATCHDTO[]
    
    
    patient 1 batch1 
    patient 2 batch2
    patient 3 batch 3
    patient 2 batch 4

Comment: Any thoughts, guys?

Comment: Please alter your question so your problem is described more clearly and present your model and your flow. I cannot help you with your current input.

Comment: I discovered the solution myself, Just need to use the transient property in the Batch table solves it.